# Problem with match_parent and wrap_content constraint layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I'm having trouble with ConstraintLayout in order to do the wrapped content into my layout. Every time I put wrap content the layout design gets like destroyed. Can somebody help me? It's about wrapping the content of the message before the date time and message status. Thanks!

Here I leave two images one with match_parent and the other with wrapped content:

[match_parent_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbndT.png)

[image]

[wrap_content_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZALO.png)

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:background="@drawable/message_sent_background">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewChatMessage"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewChatMessageDate"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="Test message sent!" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewChatMessageDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewChatMessageStatus"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageViewChatMessageStatus"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewChatMessage"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageViewChatMessageStatus"
    tools:text="12:02" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewChatMessageStatus"
    android:layout_width="18sp"
    android:layout_height="18sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_message_waiting" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Post relevant xml layout code into your question please. Do not make us go outside of the site for it.

Comment: Your textview has 0 width and it's constraints are such that it won't need any more width than what it takes up in the `wrap_content` image.

Comment: What's problem in your match_parent image?

Comment: Code is now on the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap_content tells your element to take as much as space you need and that might result in the image taking the space it needs, If you want your element to stay in constraints you should use 0dp, in constraint layout 0dp is match parent, what 0dp does is tells you elements to fill up the constraint regardless if your image is bigger or smaller than the constraints.

Please give [this](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) a read, it explains how to constraint layout works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that answer I have fully read all the documentation and found something that was the solution for me. Using layout_constraintWidth_default=wrap on the TextView worked perfectly.

Comment: I've never encountered a problem that would require me use layout_constraintWidth_default, how did it effect your UI?

Comment: Now the text message is fitting all width properly but respecting the constraint to the right. The problem before was that with match constraint without constraint width was not doing it right it was making the text width smaller and with this, it fits well sorry for my English.

Comment: Hi again I found that layout_constrainWidth_default is deprecated and I have used: app:layout_constrainedWidth="true" with the layout_with="wrap-content" and has the same effect.

Comment: Hey, layout_width and layout_height are the way to go, That's what I use, now what is this app:layout_constrainedWidth?

Comment: app:layout_constrainedWidth="true" this has no effect on may layouts.

Comment: On which layouts are not working? In mine for sure.